# Spring Data with Neo4j throwing IllegalArgumentException when using Integer id

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.neo.Model.Team;
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Integer> {

}
```

This is a simple team repository for CRUD operations. I also created a service class(shown below) with the method for retrieving the objects of Team class-

```
public Team retrieveTeam(Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
        
        Optional<Team> p=team.findById(id);
        return p.orElseThrow(()->new NotFoundException());
        
}
```

The team class itself goes like this-

```
public class Team {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private int win;
    private int loss;
    private int draw;
    private String form;
    private String name;
}
```

The getters and setters were defined by Lombok. At the moment I am passing an int variable to the service method but I have tried all combinations. I have tried creating new Integer objects from the int value, I have tried using int parameter in the retrieveTeam method followed by simply using the int value in findById but none of it is working. Also, the id is not generated but passed by me when saving the objects. I keep on getting this error-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Supplied id does not match primary index type on supplied class com.neo.Model.Team
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple error. I should have declared Integer id instead of int id in Team class.